Assessing the quality of an assembly
I am trying to run a script that assess the quality of a transcriptomic assembly, a de novo assembly using a tool called Transrate. To install the tool I followed the prompts in https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/transrate/README.html  I work on an HPC therefore I used module load mamba/23.3.1-0 created a mamba environment and called it transrate, I installed the tool using mamba install transrate and then I activated the environment called transrate using  mamba activate transrate. When I use mamba list it shows me its dependencies and when I use gem list I can see that transrate has been installed. On my bash script this is what I have:
module load mamba/23.3.1-0
# Activate the Conda environment
mamba activate transrate
echo "Assembly assessment with Transrate"
transrate --assembly /path/to/my/assembly/Trinity.fasta --left trimmed_SRR609893_1.fastq.gz --right trimmed_SRR609893_2.fastq.gz --threads 8 --output /path/to/my/output/directory/
echo "Assement complete" 

When I submit this job in a bash script using sbatch transrate.sh on my cluster I get an error log file which shows me this:
Run 'mamba init' to be able to run mamba activate/deactivate
and start a new shell session. Or use conda to activate/deactivate.

/var/lib/slurm/slurmd/job9637707/slurm_script: line 15: transrate: command not found

I don't know what the issue is because when I use the mamba init it says no changes done, and I am still able to use mamba activate or deactivate. I do not understand why it says command transrate is not found yet on that environment it is present when using "gem list".
May I please get assistance on the matter, ,or get an alternative that I can use to assess a de novo assembly.

Two things: try adding mamba init above mamba activate transrate, and you may need to install a 'patched' transrate from a different source, e.g. the Oyster River Protocol version (https://github.com/macmanes-lab/Oyster_River_Protocol/blob/master/software/orp-transrate.tar.gz)

Can you also check if the slurm job has access to the transrate binary? (i.e., take the path from which transrate from your home environment and check if that file is available in the job environment). Sometimes you might need to set the PATH variable depending on how the slurm jobs set up their environment.
